# The files and folders specified in gitignore don't grayed out in vscode remote development mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitignore, vscode-remote

The files and folders specified in gitignore don't grayed out in vscode remote development mode.

[image]

Is there something I missing? or it does not supported natively in remote development mode?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to remote development mode, but it looks like other people have run into this issue and re-cloning the repo solved it for them: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90192

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with me, solved with initializing git using `git init`.